# Отправка нескольких данных

Tags: ajax, php

Надо передать 2 DIV-а в обработчик, пока что передает только один.

**index.php**

```
    <script>
    function succes(el) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'test.php',
          data: { "id": el.parent().children('#idUser').html(), },
          success: function(data) {
            var iddatass = data.split(':');
             $("#status6-"+iddatass[0]).html(iddatass[1]);
          },
        })

    }
    </script>

<?php
$user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users"));

    echo "<div id='status6-".$user[id]."'>
    <a onClick='succes($(this));'>Кнопка</a>
    <div id='idUser'>".$user[id]."</div>
    <div id='idname'>".$user[login]."</div>
    </div>
    ";

?>
```

**test.php**

```
echo $_POST[id].":";

echo "Работает";
```

Надо передать не только `"id": el.parent().children('#idUser').html()`, а ещё `"idname": el.parent().children('#idname').html()`, только вот не знаю, как это записать правильно в **AJAX** и в **test.php**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ "id": el.parent().children('#idUser').html(),"idname": el.parent().children('#idname').html() }
```

Проверь, что возвращает

```
el.parent().children('#idUser').html()
```

и

```
el.parent().children('#idname').html()
```

Возможно, лучше вместо `.html()` использовать `.text()`.